# How to create custom range picker in flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, calendar, flutter-layout

I want to  create below type of custom range picker in flutter

[image]

I have tried use below library but i haven't found way to modified  them

- https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_date_pickers
- https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_calendar_carousel
- https://pub.dev/packages/calendarro

Is there any way to create these type of range picker in flutter?

Can any body guide me or give any hint how can i achieve these?

If need more information please do let me know. Thanks in advance. Your efforts will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to write it yourself. These packages are not customisable enough to create exactly what you want.

You can off course take a look at their code to see how they've done it.
Maybe even extend some classes to override certain functionality if the package allows that.